# How to take value from onChange to Upload Image in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, file-upload, onchange

Hello guys I got the following 2 functions:

```
 changeProfileImage=(event)=>{
       
      this.setState({file:event.target.files[0]});
      
      
  }
```

and the upload one:

```
 upload(file) {
   
    let formData = new FormData();
    const username1 = localStorage.getItem('username')
    formData.append("file", file);
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/addUserImage/'+username1,
      data: formData,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
      },
  });
  }
```

Main scope is to update the username1 image with the given one from changeProfileImage function. How can I make my Upload function taking the setState file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the file value as an argument to the upload function when you call it.
code pen: https://codepen.io/akartit/pen/PoaXgQO

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      file: null
    };

    this.changeProfileImage = this.changeProfileImage.bind(this);
    this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
  }

  changeProfileImage = (event) => {
    // Set the file value in the state
    this.setState({ file: event.target.files[0] });
  };

  upload = (file) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const username1 = localStorage.getItem("username");
    formData.append("file", file);
    return axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://webhook.site/c62f75b5-32be-4f3f-a6cd-e84f515706f4",
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.changeProfileImage} />
        <button onClick={() => this.upload(this.state.file)}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: ive tried this but still when i type console.log(this.state.file) at changeProfileImage it returns me the file that i want but in Upload Request I get 400 error

Comment: try removing the content-type : return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/addUserImage/' + username1,
  data: formData,
});

Comment: 400 means the server is unable to parse the request body

Comment: same nothing happened still 400 error

Comment: added a full codepen example

Comment: tnx a lot for taking time to explain me it works like suit much appreciated!!! If u have time im seaching now how to Display the Image I took .